# updating xcode 4.2 to 4.3 version

Tags: objective-c, xcode

After updating Xcode 4.2 to 4.3 version in my project all navigation buttons have disappeared. Source code didn't changed.

Code:

```
UIBarButtonItem * button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                  target:target
                                                  action:action];
```

It's created the button with `title = null`, but `button != nil` and `target` and `action` too.

```
button.title = @"ololo";
```

This does not work either.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your issue?

Comment: Also can you show us some more code?

Comment: oh, i'm sory. I solved the problem, was a mistake in category of UIBarButtonItem